# Using Member Variable to set address.sin_port

Tags: c++

I am currently sitting on a small C++ project, where I am trying to write a class that implements tcp sockets, when I came across the following:

```
ServerSocket::ServerSocket(uint16_t port_) {
    struct sockaddr_in _address;
    uint16_t _port = port_;
    this->bindSocket();
}

int ServerSocket::bindSocket() {
    _address.sin_port = htons(_port);
    std::cout << _address.sin_port << std::endl;
}
```

Which prints "0" and doesn't work as expected, while the following works as expected:

```
ServerSocket::ServerSocket(uint16_t port_) {
    struct sockaddr_in _address;
    this->bindSocket(port_);
}

int ServerSocket::bindSocket(uint16_t port_) {
    _address.sin_port = htons(port_);
    std::cout << _address.sin_port << std::endl;
}
```

I don't understand how the first piece of code does not work and I really hope somebody can help me to understand.

Comment: `uint16_t _port = port_;` declares a local variable.  If `_port` is a class member, then you needed to do `_port = port_;`

Comment: I understand and I feel a little bit ashamed. Thank you very much for your help kind sir! It is working as expected now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have accidentally declared a variable, instead of initializing a member:

```
ServerSocket::ServerSocket(uint16_t port_) {
    struct sockaddr_in _address; // This is redundant
    uint16_t _port = port_; // <-- oopsie
    this->bindSocket(); // redundant this
}
```

It should be:

```
ServerSocket::ServerSocket(uint16_t port_) {
    _port = port_;
    this->bindSocket();
}
```

You can try to avoid situations like these in the future if you use a list initializer

```
ServerSocket::ServerSocket(uint16_t port_) : _port(port_)
{
    bindSocket();
}
```